# Handle custom row click

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

```
<v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="medications"
      @click:row="detail"
      class="elevation-23"
    >
```

This is how I have included `@click:row` in the **v-data-table**. With this when the row is clicked the **detail** function is called. But I have some columns in the row which is used to edit and delete option. When that is clicked I want some other functions to be called which I have defined. 
But when I click that **edit or delete** options the **details** function is being called.[image]

How can I stop **@click:row** to call **detail** function when the **Actions** column is clicked.

Comment: You could attach separate function (event handler) on this specific "action" **column** rather than the entire row; in other words, you don't want to use `@click:row`.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent click event to propagate to parent row, you should use .stop modifier in child (action buttons):

```
<v-btn @click.stop="edit">Edit</v-btn>
```